# Не работает скрипт, но ошибки в консоли нет!

Tags: javascript, wordpress

есть сайт http://test2.polesia.com.ua/

есть скрипт

```
var preloader = document.getElementById('loader');
    window.DOMContentLoaded =  function() {
    if(!preloader.classList.contains('done')) {
      preloader.classList.add('done');
    }
  };
```

В консоли ошибки нет, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

> Событие **DOMContentLoaded** происходит когда весь HTML был полностью загружен и пройден парсером, *не дожидаясь* окончания загрузки таблиц стилей, изображений и фреймов. Значительно отличающееся от него событие **load** используется для отслеживания только полностью загруженной страницы.

```
let preloader = document.getElementById('loader');
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if(!preloader.classList.contains('done')) {
      preloader.classList.add('done');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Изначально код был таким:

```
var preloader = document.getElementById('loader');
window.load =  function() {
if(!preloader.classList.contains('done')) {
  preloader.classList.add('done');
}
};
```

Но, он не работал и я поменял событие на DOMContentLoaded в надежде что заработает.

Сам решил так:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$( '#loader' ).remove();
  });
```

Спасибо, всем кто помог!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#loader').addClass('done');
});
```